# __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1_firebase_app__.app is not a function

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ionic3, angular5

**Firebase provider**

```js
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase, FirebaseListObservable } from 'angularfire2/database';

@Injectable() export class FirebaseProvider {
  constructor(public afd: AngularFireDatabase) { }

  getFoodItems() {
    return this.afd.list("/foodItems");
  }

  addFood(foodName) {
    this.afd.list("/foodItems").push(foodName);
  }

  removeFood(id) {
    this.afd.list("/foodItems").remove(id);
  }
}
```

Here I am using Firebase provider (predefined methods)

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { StepperPage } from '../stepper/stepper';
import { AboutUsPage } from '../about-us/about-us';
import { FirebaseProvider } from '../../providers/firebase/firebase';
import { FirebaseListObservable } from 'angularfire2/database';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
  foodItems: FirebaseListObservable<any[]>;
  newItem = '';

  constructor(
    public navCtrl: NavController,
    public firebaseProvider: FirebaseProvider
  ) {
    this.foodItems = this.firebaseProvider.getFoodItems();
  }

  addFood() {
    this.firebaseProvider.addFood(this.newItem);
  }

  removeFood(id) {
    this.firebaseProvider.removeFood(id);
  }
}
```

**Error I am getting**

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: **WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1_firebase_app**.app is not a function
>       TypeError: **WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1_firebase_app**.app is not a function

Comment: Please don't delete and re-post questions. This can result in an automatic question ban.

Comment: @AndréKool do you have answer of this question.

Comment: Which version of angularfire2 are you using?

Comment: @SurajRao:   "angularfire2": "^4.0.0-rc0",

Comment: I could be wrong but I think you need to update the angularfire2 version and make sure you update the code according to that

Comment: Where are you getting this error? Also possible to provide a minimal repo?

Comment: @TarunLalwani - Above I have posted complete code and you telling me to provide minimal repo. I am getting issue when my app home page loaded and constructor(
    public navCtrl: NavController,
    public firebaseProvider: FirebaseProvider
  ) {
    this.foodItems = this.firebaseProvider.getFoodItems();
  } and when I will remove this then it's running properly

Comment: Did you check [here](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/1647)?

Comment: @Rajpurohit solved ?